# Trying to compile Vue.js code using webpack - error

Tags: npm, webpack, vue.js

So I am trying to compile some `vue.js` code using webpack, but when I try to run webpack from command prompt I get the following error:

`ERROR in Cannot find module 'core-js/library/fn/symbol/iterator'`.
I can't get my head around this error and I don't know if I'm missing any dependencies.
Please let me know if there's something that's not right.

Here's my `webpack.config`:

```
module.exports = {
  // This is the "main" file which should include all other modules
  entry: './view/vue/main.js',
  // Where should the compiled file go?
  output: {
    path: './layout/standard/js',
    filename: 'vue-build.js'
  },
  module: {
    // Special compilation rules
   loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue'
      }
    ]
  },
  vue: {
    loaders: {
      js: 'babel'
    }
  }
}
```

And `package.json`:

```
{
  "author": "CDG",
  "license": "ISC",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "prod": "gulp -p | webpack -p",
    "dev": "gulp watch | webpack --watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^1.0.27",
    "vue-clickaway": "^1.1.3",
    "vue-resource": "^0.9.3",
    "vue-socket.io": "^1.0.2",
    "vue-spinner": "^1.0.2",
    "vuex": "^1.0.0-rc.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.1.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.1.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.14.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.1.2",
    "babel-runtime": "^5.8.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "vue-html-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "vue-loader": "^7.3.0",
    "webpack": "^1.12.2"
  }
}
```

And `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0"],
  "plugins": ["transform-runtime"]
}
```

Please help me with this problem, it's really bugging me.
Thank you!

EDIT:

I did manage to solve the issue running `npm i core-js`, but now I have the following error when typing webpack: `ERROR in Cannot find module "./_baseClone"`, what am I missing?